# wpf binding listbox items to a static list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I really looked hard. There seems to be something I am missing. Using .net 4.5.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="a.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:a"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="201" Margin="144,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" ItemsSource="{Binding (local:myClass.myStaticList)}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="282,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace a
{
    public class myClass
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<string> myStaticList { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myListBox.Items.Add("aaa");
            myListBox.Items.Add("bbb");
            myListBox.Items.Add("ccc");
            myListBox.Items.Add("ddd");
            myListBox.Items.Add("eee");
            myListBox.Items.Add("rrr");

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            <--- Breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Real simple.
The button is used only to pause the running with a breakpoint and see whether the data was introduced from `myListBox` to `myControl.myList`.

It doesn't. `myList` remains null. What am I missing?

Help please!
TIA

Comment: There is a error in your binding but event if you would change it to `{Binding Source={x:Static local:myClass.myStaticList}}` it still will not create list for you. You have to create it and add items into that collection, not ListBox

Comment: @dkozi, First, thanks. The format I used is a .Net 4.5 format for binding to static properties. see this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/binding-static-properties-in-wpf-4-5/
Besides, could you please elaborate on your solution?

Comment: I missed that 4.5 bit but the idea is to create the list once like `public static readonly ObservableCollection<string> myStaticList = new ObservableCollection<string>()` and add to it, not the `ListBox` like `myClass.myStaticList.Add("aaa");`

Comment: @dkozi, what you suggest updates `myStaticList` (obviously) but nothing shows on `myListBox`. Even tried to set the mode to 2-way. Nope.

Comment: Did you try old way of binding? `{x:Staic ... }` lets you bind to static fields as well as properties. I am not sure if the new way requires it to be property

Comment: @dkozi. OF course. Same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84912/discussion-between-zazkapulsk-and-dkozl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance and add data to your `ObservableCollection`, not to the `ListBox` that is binding to it.

MainWindow.cs :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myClass.myStaticList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        myClass.myStaticList.Add("aaa");
        myClass.myStaticList.Add("bbb");
        myClass.myStaticList.Add("ccc");
        myClass.myStaticList.Add("ddd");
        myClass.myStaticList.Add("eee");
        myClass.myStaticList.Add("fff");
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myStaticList}">
        <ListBox.DataContext>
            <local:myClass/>
        </ListBox.DataContext>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You mean initialize, not "create an instance", right? Anyway, that's great - that did the trick. Thanks!